# substr not returning a value

Tags: php, substr

I'm trying to execute the following simple command, but it's not returning any result:

```
$val = substr($gesprek->gevormdnummer, 0, 2);
```

The `$gesprek->gevormdnummer` value is a phone number fetched from the database (stored as varchar(50)).
I'm using the Yii framework to get the data from the MS SQL Database.
I'm running PHP 5.5.8 NTS on IIS7.5.

If I echo the variable it returns for example 00497121212 or 511 depending if it's an internal or external number.

When I change `$gesprek->gevormdnummer` to for example '511', `substr` will work correctly. I've tried using `mb_substr` with UTF-8 encoding but that returns the same result.

Is there anybody who has an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you sure your variable contains anything? And not another? Because this should work

Comment: As stated in the topic, if I echo $gesprek->gevormdnummer it contains a  number, which might be 00497121212 or 511 or any other valid phone number.

Comment: Tell us what `var_dump($gesprek->gevormdnummer);` gives you.

Comment: CBroe That helped, thanks! The number was prefixed with spaces, so that's why i didn't get the data back. Or at least it looked like I didn't get anything back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CBroe gave the to finding the answer to my problem.
The string was prefixed with spaces till there we're 16 characters.

So the substr was working correctly, i got back 2 spaces, which didn't show up in the echo.

var_dump($var) gave me the insight to find this out.